# Probelm with installing python-telegram-bot : "python setup.py egg_info"

Tags: python, cmd, pip, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I want to install "python-telegram-bot" 
so I used `pip` as such:

```
pip install python-telegram-bot
```

but I get the following error , I already have Microsoft Visual C++, I have python 3+ and I use windows 10.

I also tried to install in directly but it failed...

Error:

```
C:\Users\SomeThing>pip install python-telegram-bot
Collecting python-telegram-bot
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/6c/47932a4041ee76650ad1f45a80e1422077e1e99c08a4d7a61cfbe5393d41/python_telegram_bot-11.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): certifi in c:\users\SomeThing\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from python-telegram-bot)
Collecting cryptography (from python-telegram-bot)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/95/f43d02315f4ec074219c6e3124a87eba1d2d12196c2767fadfdc07a83884/cryptography-2.7.tar.gz
Collecting future>=0.16.0 (from python-telegram-bot)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/90/52/e20466b85000a181e1e144fd8305caf2cf475e2f9674e797b222f8105f5f/future-0.17.1.tar.gz
Collecting asn1crypto>=0.21.0 (from cryptography->python-telegram-bot)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ea/cd/35485615f45f30a510576f1a56d1e0a7ad7bd8ab5ed7cdc600ef7cd06222/asn1crypto-0.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.4.1 in c:\users\SomeThing\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from cryptography->python-telegram-bot)
Collecting cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 (from cryptography->python-telegram-bot)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/1a/ab8c62b5838722f29f3daffcc8d4bd61844aa9b5f437341cc890ceee483b/cffi-1.12.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\SomeThing\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 489, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
        return self.find_available_vc_vers()[-1]
    IndexError: list index out of range

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\SomeThing\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9me3gkos\cffi\setup.py", line 127, in <module>
        if sys.platform == 'win32' and uses_msvc():
      File "C:\Users\SomeThing\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9me3gkos\cffi\setup.py", line 105, in uses_msvc
        return config.try_compile('#ifndef _MSC_VER\n#error "not MSVC"\n#endif')
      File "c:\users\SomeThing\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 227, in try_compile
        self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
      File "c:\users\SomeThing\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 133, in _compile
        self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
      File "c:\users\SomeThing\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 346, in compile
        self.initialize()
      File "c:\users\SomeThing\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 239, in initialize
        vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "c:\users\SomeThing\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 185, in msvc14_get_vc_env
        return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
      File "c:\users\SomeThing\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 843, in __init__
        self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)
      File "c:\users\SomeThing\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 485, in __init__
        self.vc_ver = vc_ver or self._find_latest_available_vc_ver()
      File "c:\users\SomeThing\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 492, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
        raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(err)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\SomeThing\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9me3gkos\cffi
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Try using `py3 -m pip install python-telegram-bot`, I dont know if itll work though, I havent used windows 10 in like a million years, it works in linux though

Comment: at least i installed it as downloaded file